# Changing JavaScript calendar dates

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a Javascript/HTML Calendar for my website. (HTML Below).

```
<table width="690" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="2" bordercolor="#999999">
<tr class="week">
    <td width="98" class="dayofweek">Sunday</td>
    <td width="98" class="dayofweek">Monday</td>
    <td width="98" class="dayofweek">Tuesday</td>
    <td width="98" class="dayofweek">Wednesday</td>
    <td width="98" class="dayofweek">Thursday</td>
    <td width="98" class="dayofweek">Friday</td>
    <td width="98" class="dayofweek">Saturday</td>
</tr>
<tr class="week" valign="top">
    <td class="day" id="d1"><div class="daynumb" id="1"></div></td>
    <td class="day" id="d2"><div class="daynumb" id="2"></div></td>
    <td class="day" id="d3"><div class="daynumb" id="3"></div></td>
    <td class="day" id="d4"><div class="daynumb" id="4"></div></td>
    <td class="day" id="d5"><div class="daynumb" id="5"></div></td>
    <td class="day" id="d6"><div class="daynumb" id="6"></div></td>
    <td class="day" id="d7"><div class="daynumb" id="7"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr class="week" valign="top">
    <td class="day" id="d8"><div class="daynumb" id="8"></div></td>
    <td class="day" id="d9"><div class="daynumb" id="9"></div></td>
    <td class="day" id="d10"><div class="daynumb" id="10"></div></td>
    <td class="day" id="d11"><div class="daynumb" id="11"></div></td>
    <td class="day" id="d12"><div class="daynumb" id="12"></div></td>
    <td class="day" id="d13"><div class="daynumb" id="13"></div></td>
    <td class="day" id="d14"><div class="daynumb" id="14"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr class="week" valign="top">
    <td class="day" id="d15"><div class="daynumb" id="15"></div></td>
    <td class="day" id="d16"><div class="daynumb" id="16"></div></td>
    <td class="day" id="d17"><div class="daynumb" id="17"></div></td>
    <td class="day" id="d18"><div class="daynumb" id="18"></div></td>
    <td class="day" id="d19"><div class="daynumb" id="19"></div></td>
    <td class="day" id="d20"><div class="daynumb" id="20"></div></td>
    <td class="day" id="d21"><div class="daynumb" id="21"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr class="week" valign="top">
    <td class="day" id="d22"><div class="daynumb" id="22"></div></td>
    <td class="day" id="d23"><div class="daynumb" id="23"></div></td>
    <td class="day" id="d24"><div class="daynumb" id="24"></div></td>
    <td class="day" id="d25"><div class="daynumb" id="25"></div></td>
    <td class="day" id="d26"><div class="daynumb" id="26"></div></td>
    <td class="day" id="d27"><div class="daynumb" id="27"></div></td>
    <td class="day" id="d28"><div class="daynumb" id="28"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr class="week" valign="top">
    <td class="day" id="d29"><div class="daynumb" id="29"></div></td>
    <td class="day" id="d30"><div class="daynumb" id="30"></div></td>
    <td class="day" id="d31"><div class="daynumb" id="31"></div></td>
    <td class="day" id="d32"><div class="daynumb" id="32"></div></td>
    <td class="day" id="d33"><div class="daynumb" id="33"></div></td>
    <td class="day" id="d34"><div class="daynumb" id="34"></div></td>
    <td class="day" id="d35"><div class="daynumb" id="35"></div></td>
</tr>
```

I have created a JavaScript function that checks the date on load, and calls the correct function to change the month accordingly. In other words, the calendar dates will always be changing. I need to create a JS function that will change the dates for each month. Below is the JavaScript that I'm using. It doesn't do anything at all. I've commented in it a lot to show you (and myself) what's going on.

```
function february() { //this is the function for February
var numbdays = 28; //February has 28 days

for (var date=1 /* February starts on Day 1 */;date<=numbdays /* make sure it doesn't exceed 28 days */;date++ /* advance the date number */) { 
    for (var id=6 /* Day 1 of Feb is on the id "6" */;id<=34 /* 6+28=34, don't exceed past id "34" */;id++ /* advance the id number */) {
        var idstring = id.toString(); //I have no clue if the toStrings even need to be here.
        var datestring = date.toString();
        document.getElementById(idstring).innerHTML = datestring; //change the text to the correct date for the correct id.
    }
}
```

}
//nothing happens...

Any ideas? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: No, you don't need `.toString()`, but what is the purpose of the inner loop? Also, it's not valid HTML4 to have an ID that begins with a number. But anyway, here's a working example of the code: http://jsfiddle.net/mDW4L/

Comment: @thesystem I'm using HTML5, if that makes a difference. And the purpose of the inner loop is to decide where to put the date. For example (if you look at that example you gave) every month doesn't start on Sunday, it starts on a certain day. In this case, February starts on a Friday. The ID for the div tag's first Friday in the month is 6 (refer to the HTML). I hope that makes sense :P.

Comment: @thesystem Also, so if I change the ids to something like x1, x2, x3, and so on, it would work?

Comment: As long as you're only supporting browsers that support HTML5, you're fine. And to address the issue of a month starting on a day later in the week, I'd just create an appropriately sized offset before the loop, and add it to the id being selected. http://jsfiddle.net/mDW4L/1/

Comment: ...but yes, if you change your ids to start with a letter, and then concatenate the letter to the number, you'd gain some compatibility. `document.getElementById("x" + (date + offset));`

Comment: @thesystem It's working for you, but not me. Haha. What's wrong with this? http://jsfiddle.net/ryfitzger227/fpjBZ/

Comment: Your script and style resources are not loaded because you're using local paths. The top-left frame of jsFiddle should only contain the content of the `<body>` element. To add remote resources, you'll need a full path, and add it using the `Resources` panel on the left.

Comment: ...open your developer console, and you'll see that it complains that  `call()` is not defined.

Comment: ...I removed extra code, and called `february()`, and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/fpjBZ/1/

Comment: ...also, notice the menu on the left where `onLoad` is selected. This means that the JavaScript code in the lower-left panel is actually placed inside an `window.onload` handler, which means any functions are not global. Choose the `no wrap (body)` option to make your code run in the global scope.

Comment: I have literally done everything you said, and when I copy and paste the code into dreamweaver and display it in Google Chrome, nothing happens. I don't get it. It's working on jsFiddle!

Comment: Disregard that. I got it working.. Just duplicated a line of code.